# How to export custom tables from R/Python to Excel?

Tags: python, r, excel, python-3.x

I have to make 2 business-like reports about media. Therefore I have to analyze data and give colleagues an excel file with multiple custom formatted tables.

Is there a way to make custom formatted tables in R or python and export them to excel?

This way I can automate formatting the 3000+ tables :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could also look into Rmarkdown and export the report to html.

Answer (score 2):

In `R` you could use the `xlsx` package to generate Excel files with customizable table formats. Here is an example that uses a list of data.frames to output one-table-per-Excel-sheet.

```
# some data in a list of dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 11:15, c = c(letters[1:5]))
df2 <- data.frame(a = 21:25, b = 111:115, c = c(letters[1:5]))
table_list = list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)

library(xlsx)
# create workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()

# create column name style object
colnames_style <- CellStyle(wb) + Font(wb, isBold=TRUE)

# lapply with custom function
lapply(names(table_list),
  function(df) {
    sheet = createSheet(wb, df)
    addDataFrame(as.data.frame(table_list[[df]]), 
      sheet = sheet, 
      row.names = FALSE, 
      colnamesStyle = colnames_style)
  } )

saveWorkbook(wb, "table.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pandas ? In python.

Answer (score 0):

You could try exploring the pandas library in Python (https://pandas.pydata.org/). After you've installed pandas, loaded your data and performed your analysis, it provides a function `pandas.to_excel()` which outputs an excel document.

Comment: Is it also possible to format the tables (color, fat lines, font style, ...) before exporting to an excel document?

Comment: For that, you would need to use Xlsxwriter (https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html)